# How do download 32 bit Ubuntu installer for another computer?

Tags: system-installation

I want to make a dvd for my old windows ME computer to upgrade to ubuntu. Please help!!!

Comment: What are you asking that isn't answered by the main installation instructions? I'm not trying to seem blithe, but I'm not sure what it is you're asking.

Comment: Doesn't show any research effort. You could have get the answer fast if you just type it in Google.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to download this ISO: http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso

[Here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04.1/) you get an overview about available Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (Xenial Xerus) images. Go [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) for other/older versions.

Comment: thanks, i already did that but i dont know... maybe use rufus to put it on a dvd?

Comment: Does this help? http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu or http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows

Comment: ill try that. Im currently downloading the iso with frostwire